# Include all path/route in next-auth middleware

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using next auth & I want to protect all my routes except signin with next-auth middleware.How can I achieve that?

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = { matcher: ["/", "/api", "/invitation", "/room/"] };
```

Currently I am doing that but it doesn't even for for /invitation/whatever